# How do I search in joined table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

My table example:

---

```
customer (id , name ....)
transactions (id , sender , receiver .....)
```

---

The sender and receiver are both related to the customer id

---

I joined the table by

```
$this->db->select('transactions.*', FALSE);


    $this->db->select('tbl_receiver.name as receiver_name,tbl_sender.name as sender_name');
    $this->db->join('customer as tbl_receiver','tbl_receiver.id=transactions.receiver');
    $this->db->join('customer as tbl_sender','tbl_sender.id=transactions.sender');
```

Now I am able to display a table like (id,receiver_name , sender_name ...)
I need a search bar that can search receiver/sender name

```
$this->db->like('receiver_name','Jackson');
```

But it said that no such column as receiver_name .
How do I let it able to search by receiver name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is my code working perfectly. you can try this stuff i hope this
>   will work for you.

```
public function index()
{
    /*$email=$this->post->input('search');*/ //OR

    $email='myEmail@test.com'; // Set email accroding you
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table1');
    $this->db->like('table1.email',$email);
    $this->db->join('table2', 'table1.email = table2.email');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $assignedData=$query->result_array();

    var_dump($assignedData); // store data in array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `'` in your like statement. It should be

```
$this->db->like('receiver_name','Jackson');
```

Also you can write Like as:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('table')
       ->where("column LIKE '%$keyword%'")->get();
```

Comment: Oh sorry , i typed it in instead of copying .In the actual code , it is correct . Will edit it here .

Comment: But than it still wouldn't work , cause it is a joined table and i am searching using the keyword i defined in joined table instead of actual column. Any more solution . Thanks.

Comment: You can replace `$this->db->like('receiver_name','Jackson');` by `$this->db->where('receiver_name LIKE '%Jackson%');`

Comment: It still end up as unknown column . I am using variable defined in joined table . It cant recognise it as it is not in column . How do i let it recognise.

Comment: Try checking `tbl_receiver.name` in like instead of `receiver_name`

Comment: Thanks man! Alot ! HAHAAHA it works !!!! Have a nice day and thanks everyone for your effort.